# TextField not editable due to Uncaught TypeError: is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, material-ui

I am pulling data from an API and appending it to TextFields where it is displayed.  I need to be able to edit the data displayed in TextFields, but I a get this `Uncaught TypeError: prev.fields is not iterable` when I try to edit or add any text to the TextFields.

This is how the TextField is populated:

```
{details["groups"]?.map((group) => {
    return (
        {group["fields"]?.map((row, index) => {
            return (
                <TextField
                    value={row?.Value || ""}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setDetails((prev) => {
                            const update = [...prev.fields];
                            update[index] = {
                                ...update[index],
                                Value: e.target.value,
                            };
                            return { ...prev, fields: update };
                        });
                    }}
                    label={row["FieldName"]}
                />
            );
        })}
    );
})}
```

This is my API request:

```
const fetchDetails = async () => {
    setDetails(await fetch(`/fiscalyears/FY2023/intakes/${params.id}/details`)
        .then((response) => response.json()));
};
```

This is an example of my data:

```
{
  "groups": [
    "GroupName": "Solution Details",
    "GroupOrder": 1,
    "fields": [
      {
        "FieldId": 19,
        "FieldOrder": 1,
        "FieldName": "Requesting Organization",
        "FieldType": "Text",
        "Value": "IT",
        "Choices": [
          null
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: `prev` is your entire object, it doesn't have a `fields` array. You would need something like `prev.group[groupIndex].fields`. I'd also encourage you to not cram as much code as possible into setDetails() calls or JSX handlers. Make it readable, and it will be easier to avoid errors such as this.

Comment: What do you mean by ``groupIndex``?  Adding ``i`` to ``details["groups"]?.map((group, i)`` and then putting that into  ``prev.group[i].fields`` results in another type error: ``Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')``

Comment: Yes, but it's `prev.groups[i].fields`

Comment: The type error is gone now, but the TextFields are not accepting any new text.  I can press any key and nothing will change in the TextField.

Comment: Here's working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-mccarthy-uxmi9?file=/src/App.js  I have included a more readable and an all-in-one version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-mccarthy-uxmi9?file=/src/App.js) was provided by [Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72138653/textfield-not-editable-due-to-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-iterable?noredirect=1#comment127462975_72138653)